# DirectXTK no member in "Mouse" for "SetWindow(HWND hwnd)"

Tags: c++, mouse, directx-11, directxtk

I was trying to implement mouse and keyboard support in my game engine using DirectXTK. It was quite simple for keyboard, but I have got a problem with implementing proper mouse support. I was following [THIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse) for implementing mouse into my engine. This article from Microsoft wiki says that I have call SetWindow, before I will be able to change mouse mode from absolute to relative. It sounds easy, but when I try to do this like this:

```cpp
auto mouse = std::make_unique<DirectX::Mouse>();
mouse->SetWindow(hwnd);
mouse->SetMode(DirectX::Mouse::Mode::MODE_RELATIVE);
```

I get an error:

```
E0135 class "DirectX::Mouse" has no member "SetWindow"
```

It looks like this method doesn't exist in Mouse class. It is weird, becuse if I remove this line with setting window it will compile, but I will fail in runtime due to this assertion in Mouse class:

```cpp
assert(mWindow != nullptr);
```

So it is required to set window, but how can I do this, when this function doesn't exist? What's worse the article from wiki is not old, it's from 18 Apr 2019. Have anyone encountered this problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the [header file](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/Mouse.h) and you'll see this

```
#if (!defined(WINAPI_FAMILY) || (WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP)) && defined(WM_USER)
    void __cdecl SetWindow(HWND window);
    static void __cdecl ProcessMessage(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
#endif
```

So it seems likely that you don't have `WINAPI_FAMILY` and/or `WM_USER` defined in a suitable way to enable the declaration of that method in the header file.

I believe `WM_USER` will be defined by `#include <windows.h>` so maybe all you need to do is place that include before `#include <mouse.h>`

Comment: You're right I had to include #include <Windows.h> before #include <Mouse.h>.

Comment: I added this detail to the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse#windows-desktop). Thanks!